# Can't join a different stackexchange site

Tags: support, stack-exchange, login, user-accounts

There are a number of Stack Exchange sister sites. I have a hard time signing up with them. I'm presented with three options:

- Sign up using Google
- Sign up using Facebook
- Sign up using Stack Exchange

I have a Stack Exchange ID, so that's what I want to use.

On filling in my **existing** name, email, and password (confirmed), I am presented with the puzzling message:

> We already have an account with that email address.
>   If the email is correct, try recovering your account.

Huh? Of course I have an account with that email address. That's what I'm trying to use!

I'm using the right email, the right password. Why do I have to enter any of that? I'm logged into three SE sites right now! Why do I have to type my password twice, and above all, why do I have to "recover my account", which I never lost?

My workaround has been to "recover my account". That means changing my password with all of my existing SE accounts.

Comment: Have you tried using the "log in" page and selecting Stack Exchange from that list?

Comment: Well. That works. "Log in" lets me use my SE account but "Sign up" doesn't? Seriously? I would call that a bug.

Comment: Hopefully they'll get that fixed up soon. The "sign up" page is trying to actually create a Stack Exchange OpenID account rather than just creating an account *on that site*. It's rather messed up.

Comment: It's very messed up. "Logging in" doesn't make sense if I'm not a member of foobarbaz.stackexchange.com but I want to join. "Log in" is what I would use after joining the site. (And if my cookie are right, I don't have log in at all. I just go to foobarbaz.stackexchange.com and voila! I'm logged in.) "Sign up" -- that's what I want to do.

Comment: @animuson - Kvetching aside, if make your comment an answer, I'll accept it. Your comment certainly did solve my problem.